# How can I fetch and use data with this design in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I have this design, I created it and put the data manually, the question is how can I get the data in the image and it is from this website (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) and display it in the same design

Answer (score 0):

```
  var url = Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

      var response = await http.get(url);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
        responseJson as List;
        return responseJson.map((e) => YourModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can paste your JSON in the [link](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) below, click convert and get your Dart classes for free.

Secondly, you can copy the result which is named `JsonPlaceHolderResponse` and create a new file in your project, and paste the result there.

Finally, you can use this code to get your data from defined API:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future<JsonPlaceHolderResponse?> getData(String url) async {
    
      final _response = await Client().get(
        url
      );
      if (_response.successResponse) {
        final _json = jsonDecode(_response.body);
        return JsonPlaceHolderResponse.fromJson(_json);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    
    return null;
  }


extension ResponseExtension on Response {
  bool get hasWrongCredentials => statusCode == 422;

  bool get tooManyRequests => statusCode == 429;

  bool get successResponse => statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300;
}
```